How to check/connect .cs file to .axml in Xamarin?
I have a Xamarin project (it's not mine, but I need to make some changes in it) where the .axml files use as Views. They are placed here .../Resources/layout/
The .cs with logic and events are placed in .../Views/
When I run the app with breakpoints in .cs files they are not hit if I press the button.
Breakpoint in protected override void OnCreate is also not hits.
I think that there is something happend that the .axml files don't have a conection to .cs files and that's why .cs files is not hited on events.
How can I check or change the association between .axml and .cs files?
